# Grunt: SASS creates unwanted .map file

Tags: css, dictionary, compilation, sass, gruntjs

I've got grunt to successfully compile SASS to CSS. The problem I'm having is it's creating a file within the CSS directory called something like **master.css.map**.

I tried writing **sourceMap: false**, which I found as being the solution for a LESS setup within the options section, whereas it doesn't make a difference.

```
sass: {
  build: {
    options: {
      compress: false,
      sourceMap: false
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'sass/',
      src: ['*.scss'],
      dest: 'css/',
      ext: '.css'
    }]
  }
}
```

Do I need to declare something else or is there a dependency that can stop the .map file from being made?

Comment: Check my edit in answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to write like this:

```
options: {
    compress: false,
    sourcemap: 'none'
  }
```

[Here's a link](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass#sourcemap) for further clarification.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Writing this makes the cmd say "**ReferenceError: none is not defined**." "**Aborted due to warnings.**" :(

Comment: make sure `sourcemap` is in all lower case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't think about writing the none as a string as well. It's working perfectly now :)